# perl: processing bad return value from decode_json()

Tags: json, perl, parsing, joomla

I'm trying to build a script that processes the JSON data within a joomla article and I don't know how to handle a failed return value from the decode_json() function.

Here is the code I'm trying to use to extract the "urls" JSON data from this article

```
 my @rv        = ();
 while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    print "urls: $ref->{'urls'}\n";
    my $decoded_urls = decode_json($ref->{'urls'}) or next;
    my $url = $decoded_urls->{'urla'};
    if ($url ne 0) {
       push @rv, $ref;
    }
  }
```

This prints the following

```
 urls: {"urla":"http://www.MimeStar.com/html/press_rel.htm","urlatext":"</i>Posted by: <a href="mailto:ben@example.com">Benjamin D.</a>","targeta":"1","urlb":false,"urlbtext":"","targetb":"","urlc":false,"urlctext":"","targetc":""}
```

Then it chokes instead of just advancing to the next article

```
 ,  or } expected while parsing object/hash, at character offset 89 (before "mailto:ben@example...") at ./find-remote-links.pl line 271.
```

How can I have the program proceed to the next row (rather than terminating) when an error occurs?

Comment: The `urlatext` attribute has embedded quotes. They need to be escaped for this json to be valid.

Comment: By the way, `{ "urla": "...", "urlb": "...", "urlc": "...",  ... }` is a horrible way of passing a list of urls. `[ "...", "...", "...", ... ]` makes far more sense. If you have any control in this matter, you should fix this.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I wasn't more clear. I was trying to figure out how to handle the exception. The "urla" "urlb" is directly from joomla, not something I've written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To catch an expection, one uses [`eval BLOCK`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

```
 my @rv;
 while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref() ) {
    print "urls: $row->{urls}\n";
    my $decoded_urls = eval { decode_json($row->{urls}) }
       or next;

    $decoded_urls->{urla}
       or next;

    push @rv, $row;
  }
```

Comment: How do I determine which $row's were malformed, or even just print them without attempting to decode them if they're somehow malformed? I'm finding there are a lot of these malformed fields and I'd like to investigate why.

Comment: @AlexRegan The intended encoded-`JSON` in Perl is a reference to a complex data structure.  You can see data in those using one of a number of modules written to print them, like the core `Data::Dumper`. For example, `my decoded_urls = eval { decode_json($row->{urls}) } or do { print "eval: $@"; say "JSON: ", pp $row->{urls}; next };` (with `use Data::Dump qw(pp);`).  See linked `eval` for `$@`. The best way to check whether a Perl data structure has valid JSON is to attempt to decode it (or you'd need to inspect a printout very closely)

Comment: Since '0' is now a valid JSON document, I would do the assignment inside the eval and force the eval to return 1 when it succeeds: `my $decoded_urls; eval { $decoded_urls = decode_json($row->{urls}); 1 } or next;` Or nicer with [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try): `use Syntax::Keyword::Try; my $decoded_urls; try { $decoded_urls = decode_json($row->{urls}); } catch { next }`

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

your problem rises from following JSON part `"urlatext":"</i>Posted by: <a href="mailto:ben@example.com">Benjamin D.</a>"`. JSON does assume that format should be `"key": "value"` and **value** does **not permit** inclusion of `"` without escaping.

You need to analyse where these extra `"` came to be from

1. if extra `"` was introduced by your code then you need to correct this part of code
2. if extra `"` comes from extraction snippet then you need to find a way to substitute
   it to `\"` or `'`.

In case **2** if this extraction snippet is consistent (predictable) then you can correct it with [regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

If extraction snippet is very dynamic and impossible to predict then you have to write a **parser** to handle gracefully at least known cases.